# Remote access to Jenkins server

Tags: python, jenkins

maybe someone can help
Deployed on an old Jenkins laptop.
Now I would like to configure access to it from a different device.
Help me please)

I tried to find information on the Internet on my question, but the search is in vain.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access it remotely, you either have to bind Jenkins to the same network as the other device.
This can be either public IP, which will then make Jenkins available to "anyone" or private IP which is shared on your home network.

How did you deploy your Jenkins? Is it containerized or running natively on your laptop?

Comment: The issues is in the question: author of the question should add more information and more information should be added by the author of the answer